# Weird error using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am using this library (PHP Simple HTML DOM parser) to parse a link, here's the code:

```
function getSemanticRelevantKeywords($keyword){
    $results = array();
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.semager.de/api/keyword.php?q=". urlencode($keyword) ."&lang=de&out=html&count=2&threshold=");
    foreach($html->find('span') as $e){
            $results[] = $e->plaintext;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

but I am getting this error when I output the results:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/efamous.de/subdomains/sandbox/httpdocs/getNewTrusts.php
>   on line 25

(line 25 is the foreach loop), the odd thing is that it outputs everything (at least seemingly) correctly but I still get that error and can't figure out why.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually means that $html isn't an object.

It's odd that you say this seems to work. What happens if you output $html?
I'd imagine that the url isn't available and that $html is null.

Edit:
Looks like this may be an error in the parser. Someone has submitted a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2949098&group_id=218559&atid=1044037) and added a check in his code as a workaround.

Comment: if I output $html I get:

simple_html_dom Object ( [root] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => div [attr] => Array ( [class] => tagcloud ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => span [attr] => Array ( [style] => font-size:100%; ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object...etc 

then at the end of the array (showed using print_r()), I get: 

[noise:protected] => Array ( ) )
1

Comment: @Luis Armando Added some more info. Seems like this may be the parsers fault.

Comment: Hi Luis, how do you solve this problem? I have the same error when I use PHP Simple HTML DOM parser

Answer (score 22):

The reason for this error is: the simple HTML DOM does not return the object if the size of the response from url is greater than 600000.
You can void it by changing the `simple_html_dom.php` file. Remove `strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE` from the `if` condition of the `file_get_html` function.
This will solve your issue.

Comment: worked for me! thanks!.. @Krumia, i agree that the answer must be formatted in a professional manner. however, if the one who answered was busy and got into the rush and just had a couple of minutes to answer it, it still serve the purpose.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to increase `CONSTANT MAX_FILE_SIZE` in file **simple_html_dom.php**.

For example:

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 999999999999999);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before `file_get_html/load_file` method, you should first check if URL exists or not.

If the URL exists, you pass one step.
(Some servers, service a 404 page a valid HTML page. which has propriate HTML page structure like body, head, etc. But it has only text "This page couldn'!t find. 404 error bla bla..)

If URL is 200-OK, then you should check whether fetched thing is object and whether nodes are set.

That's the code i used in my pages.

```
function url_exists($url){
    if ((strpos($url, "http")) === false) $url = "http://" . $url;
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    // print_r($headers);
    if (is_array($headers)){
        if(strpos($headers[0], '404 Not Found'))
            return false;
        else
            return true;    
    }         
    else
        return false;
}

$pageAddress='http://www.google.com';
if ( url_exists($pageAddress) ) {
    $htmlPage->load_file( $pageAddress );
} else {
    echo 'url doesn t exist, i stop';
    return;
}

if( $htmlPage && is_object($htmlPage) && isset($htmlPage->nodes) )
{
    // do your work here...
} else {
    echo 'fetched page is not ok, i stop';
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those arriving here via a search engine (as I did), after reading the info (and linked bug-report) above, I started some code-prodding and ended up fixing my problems with 2 extra checks after loading the dom;

```
$html = file_get_html('<your url here>');
// first check if $html->find exists
if (method_exists($html,"find")) {
     // then check if the html element exists to avoid trying to parse non-html
     if ($html->find('html')) {
          // and only then start searching (and manipulating) the dom 
     }
}
```

Comment: I get `method_exists($html,"find") == true` but still the error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error come up in my logs and apart from the solutions mentioned above, it could also be that there is no 'span' in the document. I get the same error when searching for divs with a particular class that doesn't exist on the page, but when searching for something that I know exists on the page, the error doesn't pop up.

Answer (score 0):

your script is OK.
I receive this error when it doase not find the element that i'm looking for on that page.

In your case, please check if the page that you are accessing it has 'SPAN' element

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution to this problem

```
if ($html = file_get_html("http://www.semager.de/api/keyword.php?q=". urlencode($keyword) ."&lang=de&out=html&count=2&threshold=") {

} else {
    // do something else because couldn't find html
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Error means, the find() function is either not defined yet or not available. Make sure you have loaded or include related function.

Comment: What output if you dump the `var_dump($html);` after `$html = file_get_html("http://www.semager.de/api/keyword.php?q=". urlencode($keyword) ."&lang=de&out=html&count=2&threshold=");`?

Comment: object(simple_html_dom)#1 (21) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(3) "div" ["attr"]=> array(1) { ["class"]=> string(8) "tagcloud" } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#5 (9)... etc

Comment: What PHP version you runs? `phpinfo()`

Comment: I thought that maybe your PHP version is not update, since object iteration is exist on PHP5 above. Well, it sounds like minor bug of that class.