# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, parsing

I am new to php.
I getting

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object error,

I included simple_html_dom.php

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$htm = file_get_html('http://www.thatscricket.com');

$es = $htm->find('div[class=score_card_display_below_links]');

$value = $es[0]->href;

$link = "http://www.thatscricket.com/$value";

$html = file_get_html('$link');

$scr = $html->find('span');

echo "$scr";
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird error using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832197/weird-error-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_html('$link');
```

This will try to get the literal string `'$link'` (variables aren't expanded inside single quoted strings). Which means `$html` will be null or false.

Since `$html` isn't an object you can't call methods on it.

Use:

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
```

You should also always check return types that may be false or null due to failure so that you can fail gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
$htm = file_get_html('http://www.thatscricket.com');
```

check `var_dump($htm);`
I think it returns `bool(false)`

```
$html = file_get_html('$link');
```

should be

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the `var_dump($htm)` first, it must be returning null

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same error I found it solution from php count function like this

```
if( $htm ){
     $score_card_count = count($htm->find('div[class=score_card_display_below_links]'));
     $score_card_count = trim($score_card_count);
         if( $score_card_count > 0 )
         {
              $es = $htm->find('div[class=score_card_display_below_links]');
              $value = $es[0]->href;
         }
}
```

I hope it will work fine from this approach my error is fixed.