# weird html parser error Call to a member function find()

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I have this error when parsing html

my code is like this

```
$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$type = gettype($html);
$this->output->writeln("check point1:" . $type); // it says 'object'
$class = get_class($html);
$this->output->writeln("check point2:" . $class); // it says 'simple_html_dom'
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
//do something here.
}
```

then this code shows this error sometims.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

error

even when error happens $html is correctly fetched (I check in two check points)

This error is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832197/weird-error-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser) article though, no slution is revealed.

Please help me

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `find` function?

Comment: oh,I added the code. My explanation was bad