# simple html dom parser error find function on boolean

Tags: php, html, curl

```
$html = file_get_html($response);
$displaybody = $html->find('div[id="item"]');
echo $displaybody->plaintext
```

I'm using html dom parser to and using find() funtion but i got an error like this :

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean

can someone tell me why ?

Comment: i'm guessing because the dom tag is not found.

Comment: do an if(find('div[id="item"]')) print true else print false. True, means dom tag exists, false means it doesn't ('item') can't be found

Comment: I'd suggest you output $html to debug log or console and manually see if the div id item is in fact there. $100USD says it's not there, null or blank.

Comment: Simple HTML Dom can react adversely in some cases as well; it's better if you use PHP's built in DOMDocument, and DOMXPath http://php.net/Domxpath

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer which actually worked for me.

The reason for this error is: the simple HTML DOM does not return the object if the size of the response from url is greater than 600000.
You can void it by changing the `simple_html_dom.php` file. Remove `strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE` from the `if` condition of the `file_get_html` function. This will solve your issue.

This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773587/2513964

Comment: Or just update the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` defined in that same file.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error:** Call to a member function find() on boolean

This generally means that `find('div[id="item"]')` is false or not found.

I'd suggest you output $html to console or log and verify that div id "item" is in fact in there.

Also use `DOMDocument` library and use `getElementById`

```
public DOMElement DOMDocument::getElementById ( string $elementId )
```

Should grab the first instance of 'item' (assuming if there's more than one you want the first one)