# PHP simple HTML DOM parser errors

Tags: php, html

I've started writing a scraper for one site that will also have a crawler, since I need to go through some links, but I'm getting this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on
> null in D:\Projekti\hemrank\simple_html_dom.php:1129 Stack trace:
>
> 0 D:\Projekti\hemrank\scrapeit.php(37): simple_html_dom->find('ul')
>
> 1 D:\Projekti\hemrank\scrapeit.php(19): ScrapeIt->getAllAddresses()
>
> 2 D:\Projekti\hemrank\scrapeit.php(55): ScrapeIt->run()
>
> 3 {main}   thrown in D:\Projekti\hemrank\simple_html_dom.php on line 1129

When I var_dump the $html variable I get the full html with all the tags, etc, that's why it's strange to me that it says "Call to a member function find() on null", when there's actually value in the $html. Here's the part of the code that's not working :

```
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($baseurl);
        if(empty($html)){echo "HTTP Response not received!<br/>\n";exit;}
        $links = array();
        foreach ($html->find('ul') as $ul) {
            if(!empty($ul) && (count($ul)>0))
            foreach ($ul->find('li') as $li) {
                if(!empty($li) && (count($li)>0))
                foreach ($li->find('a') as $a) {
                    $links[] = $a->href;
                }
                else
                    die("NOT AVAILABLE");
            }
        }
        
        return $links;

    }
```

Is this a common problem with PHP simple HTML DOM parser, is there a solution or should I switch to some other kind of scraping?

Comment: PHP does not provide a [`simple_html_dom`](http://php.net/results.php?q=simple_html_dom&l=en&p=all) class.

Comment: I think It should be just `$html = file_get_html($baseurl);`

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832197/weird-error-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser)

Comment: @axiac no it doesn't, you download it and include it in the file where you're going to use it..

Comment: @DanMiller Tried that way also, didn't work, same errors. file_get_html is just a short way for  new simple_html_dom(); then ->load(url);, it just does both for you in the background

Comment: maybe you may take a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, it's a good php library for scraping

Comment: @teeyo that's the one I'm asking a question about.... the whole title says PHP simple HTML DOM error

Comment: @MirzaS then is `$baseurl` local or remote HTML file ? because in the docs they use `$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');` for remote files.

Comment: @teeyo it's remote, it's a link for a website, I've tried doing file_get_html($baseurl) but I get error 
 >Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in D:\Projekti\hemrank\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Comment: @MirzaS because I think `file_load` is used for local files, and maybe you can try `file_get_contents` to load the page HTML and then use `str_get_html` to get your $html variable like this : `$html = str_get_html(/*file_get_contents_result*/);`

Comment: @MirzaS oh, **that's** the one. And you probably expect others to guess what library are you using. [Edit] the question and put the url where the library can be found and also the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched for the lib you are using, this is line 1129:

```
return $this->root->find($selector, $idx, $lowercase);
```

So your error message is telling you that `$this->root` inside the class is `null`, therefore no `find()` method exists!

I'm no expert on the lib, as I use the awesome DOMDocument for parsing HTML, but hopefully this should help you understand what has happened.

Also, `$html` will never be empty in that code of yours, you already populated it when you instantiated it!

Comment: It's possible, and it could be the first `$html->find('ul')` which means the `$html->load_file($baseurl)` couldn't load the file!

Comment: `var_dump($html)`, to see what `root` is actually set at

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following change:

`$html->load_file($baseurl);` to `$html = file_get_html($baseurl);`

On my VPS server it works with `$html->load_file($baseurl);` but on my dedicated local server it only works with `$html = file_get_html($baseurl);`

This solved my problem:
- Call to a member function `find()` on null
- `simple_html_dom.php` on line 1129